# Scope of PCI DSS regarding CVV

Tags: pci-dss

According to PCI SSC, you can hold onto a CVV and other sensitive authentication data until authorization has occurred. In other words, the restriction on storing sensitive authentication data applies to post authentication/processing storage.

Are the machines that the CVV is stored on until authorization in scope?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: I believe they are but I'm receiveing push back because I'm unable to get a black and white response from the PCI DSS SSC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the machines store, process, or transmit cardholder information (CHD) and/or sensitive authentication data (SAD), therefore they are in scope.

[image: PCI DSS page 7]
[image: PCI DSS page 10]

Comment: Is there any official documentation out there from PCS DSS SSC that states that?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my answer to include a screenshot from page 7 and page 10 of PCI DSS 3.2.

Comment: Thank you John. You confirmed what I suspected. In relation to Tokenization I'm wondering How it will be viewed for Pre-Authorization? Would the machines be in scope because of the pre-authorization process? After authorization the information is deleted.

Comment: If the machines have access to the value before tokenization, it doesn't matter, they're still in scope. The part with prior to authorization is only about storage.